# PHP and MySQL to plot times on graph

Tags: php, mysql, graphics, gd

I have the below MySQL output in the form of a table.

[image: mysql output]

What I want to do is plot each geofence time on a horizontal time line, something like below:

[image]

The theory is that I create the time axis as a table row. The starting and end points being the time (15 min intervals), Early Time as starting point and the Late Time as end point.

In the second row, I want to have dynamic 'boxes', generated with `imagefilledrectangle`. The starting co-ordinate and end co-ordinate of each 'box' is to be the InSeconds and OutSeconds from the table. Then obviously I need multiple 'boxes' per row to represent each visit to a geofence.

I read a few articles on `imagefilledrectangle` but I am not sure where to start and how to get multiple boxes. Obviously the boxes need to correlate to the time in the first table row.

Currently my query to generate the data table is: (excuse the `mysql_query`, will convert to PDO at a later stage):

```
$result = mysql_query("

      select * from (select
      PreQuery.callingname as vehicle,
      PreQuery.geofence,
      PreQuery.GroupSeq,
      MIN( PreQuery.`updatetime` ) as InTime,
      UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MIN( PreQuery.`updatetime`))as InSeconds,
      MAX( PreQuery.`updatetime` ) as OutTime,
      UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MAX( PreQuery.`updatetime`))as OutSeconds,
            TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME((MAX( PreQuery.`updatetime` )-MIN( PreQuery.`updatetime` ))),'%H:%i') as Duration,
      round((MAX( PreQuery.`updatetime` )-MIN( PreQuery.`updatetime` )),0) as DurationSeconds

   from
     ( select
              v_starting.callingname,
              v_starting.geofence,
              v_starting.`updatetime`,
              @lastGroup := @lastGroup + if( @lastAddress = v_starting.geofence 
                                         AND @lastVehicle = v_starting.callingname, 0, 1 ) as GroupSeq,
              @lastVehicle := v_starting.callingname as justVarVehicleChange,
              @lastAddress := v_starting.geofence as justVarAddressChange
           from
              v_starting,
              ( select @lastVehicle := '',
                       @lastAddress := '',
                       @lastGroup := 0 ) SQLVars
           order by
              v_starting.`updatetime` ) PreQuery
   Group By
      PreQuery.callingname,
      PreQuery.geofence,
      PreQuery.GroupSeq) parent

      where geofence <>'' and InTime>  DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 72 HOUR) and vehicle='TT08' and Duration>0 order by InTime asc


");
```

My syntax to generate table is simply:

```
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <th>Vehicle</th>
        <th>Geofence</th>
        <th>InTime</th>
        <th>InSeconds</th>
        <th>OutTime</th>
        <th>OutSeconds</th>
        <th>Duration</th>
        <th>DurationSeconds</th>
    </tr>

    <?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['vehicle'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['geofence'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['InTime'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['InSeconds'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['OutTime'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['OutSeconds'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Duration'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['DurationSeconds'] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </table>
```

So I am being a bit cheeky but if anyone can give me advice on how to get started that would be great. Alternatively a good article I could read or use as a reference.

Is a imagefilled rectangle the correct route to go? Are there any JavaScript solutions or plugins I can use?

Comment: You could draw rectangles on a PNG image, draw on a browser Canvas, or render the data in an HTML table with merged cells. Not sure what the problem is, though: sort your query by start time, and then render each row in order. If you wish to draw to a PNG image, then have a look in the PHP manual for how to call it, and give it a go.